# Factorization algorithm to solve this system?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

What is the best factorization algorithm to solve this system? (Best is intended as more stable)

$$ AA^Tx = b $$

```
x, b vectors
```

Comment: $x$ is a matrix or number?

Comment: x and b are vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix product $AA^T$ yields a symmetric and positive semi-definite matrix (assuming that $A$ is real), hence you can use a [Cholesky factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition). However, I don't know for sure if this is the "best."